# Service is already initialized, you cannot replace it when trying to mock class with doctrine.event_subscriber tag

Tags: php, symfony, testing, doctrine

I'm trying to mock some class in functional test. I have configuration for such class like this:

```
        <service id="some.class"
                 class="Some\Namespace\SomeClass">
            <tag name="doctrine.event_subscriber"/>

            <argument type="service" id="some_service"/>
        </service>
```

And then in test I try to:

```
        self::$container->set('some.class', $someMock);
```

And when I run test with such line I got such error:
`Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: The "some.class" service is already initialized, you cannot replace it.`

But I've managed to see that without doctrine tag it is just working correctly. Why it's an issue and how can I fix it?

Symfony version: 4.4
Doctrine/orm: 2.7

Answer (score 0):

I've manage to fix the issue. But first answer why an error happens.

It happens because all subscribers are initialized when container is created and not when needed which makes sense but in tests it is wrong. All that happens in class named: `ContainerAwareEventManager`. So that's why I couldn't update this service because it already exists

The solution I've manage to get is instead of using configuration for subscriber I've subscribed to doctrine events in constructor. So solution looks like this:

```
    public function __construct(
        EntityManager $entityManager
    ) {
        $entityManager->getEventManager()->addEventListener(
            [Events::postFlush],
            $this
        );
    }
```